# How can I explain the meaning of "exact cover "

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

I want to explain the `exact cover problem` to my colleagues who don't have any mathematical background as such. I want to explain them where it can be used and how? So my question goes like this: **How can I explain the exact cover problem to someone who don't have a mathematical background or rather to children and make it more interesting and intuitive?** With this I also want to explain the concept of `P-NP (in general)` as well.

Comment: [Explain P = NP problem to 10 year old](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/explain-p-np-problem-to-10-year-old)

Comment: You are putting the set elements into baskets, so each element goes into exactly one basket.

Comment: You have a bunch of light bulbs. Those are vertices. What can you do to literally "cover" them?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but I'm not sure which site would be best. math.stackexchange.com, cs.stackexchange.com, cstheory.stackexchange.com, or maybe even matheducators.stackexchange.com (that might be a stretch). Please check each of these sites for their posting guidelines, though.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed and elaborated answer, please?

Comment: How would **you** explain it? I feel like there are many analogies you could make for a set cover

Comment: Like, all inputs have some output.  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/96/Exact-cover-bigraph-highlighted.svg/1024px-Exact-cover-bigraph-highlighted.svg.png

Comment: Each people having a phone number directory of others inside the same city, is it possible to find a set of people such that every phone number is catched (covers all phone numbers) and only once (exact).

Comment: Add this as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good analogy here is a puzzle.

Let's say there is a square on the floor you want to cover, but instead of having the regular setup where you have the exact amount and shapes to cover it once and they all fit in a certain way, you have enough pieces to cover it many times.

The problem is to find a bunch of pieces that:
A. They all fit together (no overlaps, no gaps).
B. They cover the right surface area (the square you have).

Answer (score 0):

Each people having a phone number directory of others inside the same city, is it possible to find a set of people such that every phone number is catched (covers all phone numbers) and only once (exact).